# OpsCenter fails to fetch keyspaces from single cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Got an OpsCenter monitoring 3 Clusters, one now fails to show it's keyspaces and thus I fail to run actions against it f.ex. compacting otherwise monitoring seems fine against same cluster all agents are connected etc.

I find this in opscenterd.log:

```
2015-08-26 11:03:47+0200 [] ERROR: An error occurred while retrieving all keyspaces.  Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 933, in InspectKeyspaceController
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 406, in keyspaces_as_data
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 406, in <genexpr>
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 360, in _to_table_bools
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 963, in export_as_string
            ret += "\nApproximate structure, for reference:\n(this should not be used to reproduce this schema)\n\n%s" % self.all_as_cql()
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 969, in all_as_cql
            ret = self.as_cql_query(formatted=True)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 1000, in as_cql_query
            columns.append("%s %s%s" % (protect_name(col.name), col.typestring, ' static' if col.is_static else ''))
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 1089, in protect_name
            return maybe_escape_name(name)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 1118, in maybe_escape_name
            return escape_name(name)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra/metadata.py", line 1122, in escape_name
            return '"%s"' % (name.replace('"', '""'),)
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
2015-08-26 11:03:47+0200 []  WARN: InternalError while calling InspectKeyspaceController: An error occurred while retrieving all keyspaces.
```

Though the cluster it self gives me this and nothing to see in the clusters log:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.16 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> describe keyspaces;

KeyspaceMetadata  system  OpsCenter  system_traces

cqlsh> select * from system.schema_keyspaces;

 keyspace_name    | durable_writes | strategy_class                                       | strategy_options
------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 KeyspaceMetadata |           True | org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy |             {"SPRAWL":"2"}
        OpsCenter |           True |          org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"2"}
           system |           True |           org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy |                         {}
    system_traces |           True |          org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"2"}

(4 rows)
```

Wondering where to begin, other 2 cluster doesn't show issues, no changes have been made since last operational.
Tried restart node by node incl. datastax agents and OPsCenter as well, but no changes, still can't fetch key spaces from this one cluster.

Hints appreciated, TIA!

Comment: what version of OpsCenter are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Root of this issue is a bug in the driver described here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-192. Do you have some complex thrift tables? It may be worth updating the contents of /usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/cassandra to be the latest version of driver with the fix or

Comment: I'm not aware of any complex thrift tabels and ImHO nothing have changed between time when it was working and now, also other two instances are working fine from same OpsCenter...

Comment: What are the latest version of this driver and where to find it?  BTW since then updated to OpsCenter 5.2.2, but problem persist for just this one out of three cluster, hence seem issue would be on the cluster side rather than on the OpsCenter side.

Comment: 2016-02-01 11:41:31+0100 [] ERROR: An error occurred while retrieving all keyspaces.  Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 942, in InspectKeyspaceController
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 445, in keyspaces_as_data
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 445, in <genexpr>
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 399, in _to_table_bools
...

Comment: Still problem via cql: [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.17 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> describe keyspaces;

KeyspaceMetadata  system  OpsCenter  system_traces